# Pandas groupby use aggregate based on two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Imagine I have the following dataframe:

```
np.random.seed(42)
t = pd.DataFrame({'year': 4*['2018']+3*['2019']+4*['2016'], 
                  'pop': np.random.randint(10, 100, size=(11)),
                 'production': np.random.randint(2000, 40000, size=(11))})

print(t)
year  pop  production
 2018   61        3685
 2018   24        2769
 2018   81        4433
 2018   70        7311
 2019   30       39819
 2019   92       19568
 2019   96       21769
 2016   84       30693
 2016   84        8396
 2016   97       29480
 2016   33       27658
```

I want to find the sum of production divided by the sum of the pop by each year, my final dataframe would be something like:

```
tmp = t.groupby('year').sum()

tmp['production']/tmp['pop']

year
2016    322.909396
2018     77.110169
2019    372.275229
```

I was thinking if it could be done using groupby year and then using agg based on two columns, something like:

```
#doesn't work
t.groupby('year').agg(prod_per_pop = (['pop', 'production'], 
                         lambda x: x['production'].sum()/x['pop'].sum()))
```

My question is basically if it is possible to use any pandas groupby method to achieve that in an easy way rather than having to create another dataframe and then having to divide.

Comment: It might be possible with `groupby().apply()`, but I'd go for the `tmp` approach.

Comment: Why would you use that approach? For me, it looks messier because you have to create a new data frame just for that simple calculation, is there any performance reasons? @QuangHoang

Comment: Yes, for example, in the accepted answer, you created the dataframe anyway, and then chain it with `apply`, which is generally slower simple series division. Plus, I personally find this approach more readable than chaining with `apply(lambda x:...)`. Then again, it's just personal preference and the performance difference is not that big for most of application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use lambda functions with `axis=1` to solve it in single line.

```
t.groupby('year')['pop','production'].agg('sum').apply(lambda x: x['production']/x['pop'], axis=1)
```